# Attempting to install a specific version of Regex under Python getting a Type Error to do with the path

Tags: python, regex, pip, installation, typeerror

W10
Python 3.7.2
Pip3 19.3.1

Am trying to install regex as part of a larger install using the following command line:

```
pip install regex==2017.4.5
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

With the following stack trace:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\py\py\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mkqyqr4j\\regex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mkqyqr4j\\regex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vkvvafct\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\py\py\include\site\python3.7\regex'
     cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mkqyqr4j\regex\
Complete output (61 lines):
c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:476: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.04.05' to '2017.4.5'
  normalized_version,
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying Python3\regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying Python3\_regex_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying Python3\test_regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
running build_ext
building '_regex' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mkqyqr4j\regex\setup.py", line 56, in <module>
    os.path.join(PKG_BASE, '_regex_unicode.c')])],
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\py\py\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1620, in return_env
    if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):
  File "c:\py\py\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
----------------------------------------
```

Figure maybe my config is off as installing something as basic as regex shouldn't be a show stopper

Any advice gratefully received

Comment: Try `pip install "regex==2017.4.5"`

Comment: Tried pip install "regex==2017.4.5" still getting the same issue

Comment: @AlexanderSantos In what way that should help? Quotes will be removed by shell.

Comment: For clarification it is trying to install regex before I get the error

Comment: It was just a try lol  @BigIan did you try doing user installation? `pip install "regex==2017.4.5" --user`

Comment: That just errors :|

Comment: line `if self.vs_ver >= 14 and isfile(self.VCRuntimeRedist):` can means that it need `Visual C/C++ Runtime Redistribution pack (version 14+)`  with some `dll` files which can be needed to run it.. See [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145) but I'm note sure if it is version 14 or newer or older.

Comment: tried newer and older still getting the same :|